# How to know the error in which specific file, Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4

I got `Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"`

```
% RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile                                                                                                                 (git)-[feature/prettier_form] 
(in /Users/ll/Dropbox/Rails/dqa_dev_server)
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"
  (in /Users/ll/Dropbox/Rails/dqa_dev_server/vendor/themes/lenord-single-page-theme/application.css)
(sass):7331
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

### UPDATE

I don't know why it showed me that the error was at line `7731`

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"
  (in /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/Dropbox/Rails/dqa_dev_server/vendor/themes/lenord-single-page-theme/application.css)
(sass):7331
```

But actually the application.css only has few lines. I think the problem is in other files, but how could I know in which file, and which line ?

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/poc7667/954ffe8dff67741d40b2/raw/20a77a3ef81491529dd55d927b3063c8a1c33620/style.css You have unmatched "}" character.

Comment: @newBike how did u resolved this issue

Answer (score 3):

You really could have found that yourself if you made any effort whatsoever. Stackoverflow is not your personal debugger.

[image]

Comment: I updated the post, and got another problem , thanks

Answer (score 1):

On line 815 you have an extra `}`, just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an extra '}' in your css at line 815